# MudBlazor: How to remove padding from TitleContent in MudExpansionPanel

Tags: padding, mudblazor

Looking to align `TitleContent` with `ChildContent` left. This expansion panel is in a tight space and I'd like to remove the gutters on the title content but `DisableGutters` only seems to apply to `ChildContent`:

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N99El.png)

TryMudblazor:
https://try.mudblazor.com/snippet/QEQwYmkTgJGCChXP

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[From GitHub MudBlazor Discussions](https://github.com/MudBlazor/MudBlazor/discussions/3887#discussioncomment-2119267):

You have to use CSS to call out the `mud-expand-panel-header` class

```
<style>
    .my-panels .mud-expand-panel-header { padding: 0px; }
</style>

<MudExpansionPanels Class="my-panels" Elevation="0" DisableGutters="true" Dense="true">
    <MudExpansionPanel Dense="true" Style="padding: 0px;">
        <TitleContent>
                <MudText Class="mud-text-primary">$[ItemPrice1] [ItemPrice1Label]</MudText>
        </TitleContent>
        <ChildContent>
                <MudText Class="mud-text-primary">$[ItemPrice2] [ItemPrice2Label]</MudText>
                <MudText Class="mud-text-primary">$[ItemPrice3] [ItemPrice3Label]</MudText>
        </ChildContent>
    </MudExpansionPanel>
</MudExpansionPanels>
```